# difference between Debug mode version and release mode Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a problem with the Flutter application,  The application works well in the debug mode, but when I run on the release mode, part of the widget disappears and The application does not use the internet

i write in build.grale

```
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

    }
}
```

and i use flutter run --release , flutter build apk --release

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiFNr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiFNr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8RAl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8RAl.png

Comment: What do you mean by "The application does not use the internet"? You mean your application doesn't connect to internet in release build or you don't use any internet connection in the application at all?

Comment: yes i  don't use any internet connection in the application at all